# Spark (Scala) - Reverting explode in a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have initially a DataFrame like follows:

```
Key     Emails                      PassportNum     Age
0001    [Alan@gmail,Alan@hotmail]   passport1       23
0002    [Ben@gmail,Ben@hotmail]     passport2       28
```

I need to apply a function over each Email, something dummy like add "_2" at the end for example, the operation is not relevant. So I will explode this column like this:

```
val dfExplode = df.withColumn("Email",explode($"Emails")).drop("Emails")
```

Now I will have a dataframe like this:

```
Key     Email           PassportNum     Age
0001    Alan@gmail      passport1       23
0001    Alan@hotmail    passport1       23
0002    Ben@gmail       passport2       28
0002    Ben@hotmail     passport2       28
```

I apply any change on passports and then what I want to have is again this:

```
Key     Emails                          PassportNum     Age
0001    [Alan_2@gmail,Alan_2@hotmail]   passport1       23
0002    [Ben_2@gmail,Ben_2@hotmail]     passport2       28
```

The option I was considering was this:

```
dfOriginal = dfExploded.groupBy("Key","PassportNum","Age").agg(collect_set("Email").alias("Emails"))
```

In this case it may not be such a bad approach. But in my real case I perform the explode over a single column and I have another 20 columns like PassportNum, Age... which are going to be duplicated.

This means that I will need to add around 20 columns in the groupBy, when I really can perform the group by over a single one, for example Key which is unique.

I was thinking to add this columns in the agg as well like this:

```
dfOriginal = dfExploded.groupBy("Key").agg(collect_set("Email").alias("Emails"),collect_set("PassportNum"),collect_set("Age"))
```

But I don't want them to be in a single element array.

Is it any way to make an aggregate without any `collect_*`? Is there any simpler approach to undo the `explode`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `first` for `PassportNum` and `Age` since they will have the same values anyway after the explode ?

Comment: You mean after the collect use first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to stay in the DataFrame world, it might be worth it to define a UDF that manipulates your input array. Something that takes a Seq as an input and returns a modified one. e.g.

```
def myUdf = udf[Seq[String], Seq[String]] { 
    inputSeq => inputSeq.map(elem => elem + "_2")
}

df.withColumn("Emails", myUdf($"Emails"))
```

Even better, you could pass the exact logic as a parameter:

```
def myUdf(myFunc: String => String) = udf[Seq[String], Seq[String]] {
    inputSeq => inputSeq.map(myFunc)
}

df.withColumn("Emails", myUdf((email: String) => email + "_XYZ")($"Emails"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I prefer to avoid that since the content of the array is a Map<string,string> which I will need to convert each field of the map into a column

Comment: Not sure if you understand the issue exactly. Can't you pass as an input a `Seq[Map[String, String]]`? After that you can do anything in just Scala

Comment: I will try that

Comment: I think I will follow your solution. Could you please give me an example if I pass to the udf something like Seq[Map[String, String]] how could I access a specific field in the map to apply another udf over it? So something like if the map has field1,field2,field3 => field1,field2,udf2(field3) I am not sure if this is even possible

Comment: At that point your `inputSeq` will be a `Seq[Map[String, String]]`. So something like this: `inputSeq.map(_.get("myKey"))` should help getting you started. It will return a `Seq[String]` where the strings are all the Map values for your "myKey"

Comment: Basically, once you are inside the first UDF then you are working in pure Scala with its objects and data structures. You don't need a "second UDF" to extract stuff from the Map

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, but I am very noob in Spark and Scala still. I opened a new question with what I was trying without success following your recommendation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49623370/1773841

Answer (score 1):

Another option except the groupby on all common fields is to  do the explode on a separate temporary dataframe then drop the exploded column from the original and join the re-grouped by

However it might be simpler to write a UDF that would manipulate the array directly without going into explode and gather

```
def handleEmail(emails: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) = {
     emails.map(dosomething)
  }

context.udf.register("handleEmailsm"m (em:mutabe.WrappedArray[String]) => handleEmail(em))
```

Comment: Thanks Arnon, But I prefer to use the UDF approach you mention since the content of the array is a Map<string,string> which I will need to convert each field of the map into a column

Answer (score 1):

> > This means that I will need to add around 20 columns in the groupBy, when I really can perform the group by over a single one, for example Key which is unique.

You can **skip writing each column names** by doing *a simple trick* as below where you can *use all of the column names* ( or selected ones) *except for the exploding column* names

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfExploded = df.withColumn("Emails", explode($"Emails"))

val groupColumns = dfExploded.columns.filterNot(_.equalsIgnoreCase("Emails"))

val dfOriginal = dfExploded.groupBy(groupColumns.map(col): _*).agg(collect_set("Emails").alias("Emails"))
```

**Creating a struct column**

You can *create a single column by using struct inbuilt function* and *use that single column in groupBy* as

```
val groupColumns = df.columns.filterNot(_.equalsIgnoreCase("Emails"))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfExploded = df.select(struct(groupColumns.map(col): _*).as("groupedKey"), col("Emails"))
  .withColumn("Emails", explode($"Emails"))
```

which would give you

```
+-------------------+------------+
|groupedKey         |Emails      |
+-------------------+------------+
|[0001,passport1,23]|Alan@gmail  |
|[0001,passport1,23]|Alan@hotmail|
|[0002,passport2,28]|Ben@gmail   |
|[0002,passport2,28]|Ben@hotmail |
+-------------------+------------+
```

and then *use the groupedKey in groupBy and again separate them in select*

```
val dfOriginal = dfExploded.groupBy("groupedKey").agg(collect_set("Emails").alias("Emails"))
  .select($"groupedKey.*", $"Emails")
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick Ramesh. But actually I don't want to avoid that solution because of the length of the query, but because of how expensive could be a groupBy over 20 columns. As I understand the less columns in the groupBy, the faster, isn't?

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Comment: For a use case I needed to do the similar work but using this method I faced an error due to the structure of mapping column that existed in my data. Any thought on the data which we have a column of map string structure how this work can be done?