# Spark - How to apply a udf over single field in a Seq[Map<String,String>]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a Dataframe with two columns of types String and Seq[Map[String, String]]. Something like:

```
Name    Contact
Alan    [(Map(number -> 12345   , type -> home)),   (Map(number -> 87878787 , type -> mobile))]
Ben     [(Map(number -> 94837593    , type -> job)),(Map(number -> 346      , type -> home))]
```

So what I need is to apply a `udf` over the field `number` in each Map[String,String] o each element in the array. This `udf` will basically convert into 0000 any `number` which length is less than 6. Something like this:

```
def valid_num_udf = 
udf((numb:String) =>
{ 
if(numb.length < 6)
   "0000"
else 
    numb 
})
```

The expected result is something like:

```
NAME    CONTACT
Alan    [(Map(number -> 0000    , type -> home)),   (Map(number -> 87878787 , type -> mobile))]
Ben     [(Map(number -> 94837593    , type -> job)),(Map(number -> 0000     , type -> home))]
```

What I would like is to use another udf to access each `number` field to then apply the `valid_num_udf()`

I was trying something like this, but I don't know what is the correct syntax to do this in Scala.

```
val newDf = Df.withColumn("VALID_CONTACT", myUdf($"CONTACT"))

//This part is really really wrong, but don't know better
def myUdf = udf[Seq[Map[String, String]], Seq[Map[String, String]]] { 
    inputSeq => inputSeq.map(_.get("number") => valid_num_udf(_.get("number")))
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to access just that one single field in the map, leaving the other fields of the map untouched?

**Update**: The Schema of the DataFrame would be

```
root
 |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTACT: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

or

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(NAME,StringType,true), StructField(CONTACT,ArrayType(MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true),true))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A udf function would require a column to be passed as arguments which go through serialization and deserialization to be converted to primitive data types**. So *when the column values reach udf function they are already primitive data types*. So **you can't call another udf function from a udf function unless you convert the primitive types to column types.**

What you can do *instead of defining and calling another udf function* is to just *define a simple function and call that function from the udf function*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def valid_num_udf(number: String) = number.length < 6 match{
  case true => "0000"
  case false => number
}
def myUdf = udf((inputSeq: Seq[Map[String, String]]) => {
  inputSeq.map(x => Map("number" -> valid_num_udf(x("number")), "type"-> x("type")))
})
```

and then just call the `udf` function from `withColumn` api

```
val newDf = Df.withColumn("VALID_CONTACT", myUdf($"Contact"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature of your UDF is slightly incorrect. You'll pass `Seq[Map[String, String]]` as the input :

```
val validNumber = udf{ (xs: Seq[Map[String, String]]) => 
                        xs.map{ x => 
                          if (x("number").length < 6) 
                             Map("number" -> "0000" , "type" -> x("type")) 
                          else x }
                     }

 df.show(false)
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name|contact                                                                      |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Alan|[Map(number -> 6789, type -> home), Map(number -> 987654321, type -> mobile)]|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+


df.select(validNumber($"contact") ).show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|UDF(contact)                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[Map(number -> 0000, type -> home), Map(number -> 987654321, type -> mobile)]|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @philantrovert Could you tell me how it would be if instead of applying to x the logic of validNumber, I would invoque another udf function. The reason for this is this is just a dummy example where I check length, but I would like to have a udf function apart which can grow up and make the logic more complex

Comment: `xs.map { x => ... }` Here `x` is one single `Map[String, String]` entry. You can apply any operation in the UDF that are allowed to perform on Scala Maps. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So far I have one single rule. Length < 6. But I will keep adding rules, maybe 10 or so. So to don't have such a long if else, I was planning to create another upf where I will pass just the "number" and there I will apply one by one the rules. It is as you have written, but in an independent udf which will be call for each "number" field of each map in the array.

Comment: Check @Shaido 's edit. Defining a Scala function that contains all the rules, and then calling that Scala function inside your UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two separate `UDF`s, you can use a single one which takes the whole `Seq[Map[String, String]]` as input and transforms it. This should be both faster and better than having it as two separate `UDF`.

```
val valid_num_udf = udf((seq: Seq[Map[String, String]]) => {
  seq.map{ m => 
    m.get("number") match {
      case Some(number) if number.length < 6 => m + ("number" -> "0000")
      case _ => m 
    }
  } 
})
```

Using the provided dataframe:

```
df.withColumn("Contact", valid_num_udf($"Contact"))
```

will give

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Name|Contact                                                                     |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Alan|[Map(number -> 0000, type -> home), Map(number -> 87878787, type -> mobile)]|
|Ben |[Map(number -> 94837593, type -> job), Map(number -> 0000, type -> home)]   |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

To have the logic separated from the rest, you don't need to call a separate `UDF`, simply add the logic to a method and call that. For example,

```
def valid_num(number: String) = 
  if (number.length < 6)
    "0000"
  else
    number

val myUdf = udf((seq: Seq[Map[String, String]]) => {
  seq.map{ m => 
    m.get("number") match {
      case Some(number) => m + ("number" -> valid_num(number))
      case _ => m 
    }
  } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Shaido I like this match-case approach, but as I mention in the other answer, I would like to have a second udf function where I could keep adding logic. But It is a nice approach which I will consider

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre Added more information to the answer regarding dividing up the udf